# jQuery and creating HTML are strings required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written the below code to be an e-mail signature.

What I am confused about is what is the best way to split it up (Do I have to? I have seen some places split every line up into a string) so that I can fill in the variables that I have set within my jQuery.

This is a snippet of my code however I have a form that allows me to generate the below HTML code within a textbox for copying (But I just need to know the best way to fill it in) :)

I have also included my current jQuery snippet so you can get an idea of what I have

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:500px; height:459px;">
        <div>
            <p style="margin:0 0 5px 10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">
            Name</p>

            <p style="margin:0 0 5px 10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">
            Position</p>

            <p style="margin:0 0 5px 10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">
            Lodge</p>
        </div>

        <div><img alt="Lodge" height="164" src=
        "Logo Url" style=
        "margin:10px 0 0 0;" width="257"></div>

        <div>
            <p style="margin:0 0 0 10px; color:#ccc; font-size:10px;">
            Address</p>

            <p style="margin:0 0 0 10px; font-size:10px">Email</p>

            <p style="margin:0 0 0 10px; color:#ccc; font-size:10px">Phone</p>

            <p style="margin:0 0 0 10px; font-size:10px"><span>Website</span> |
            <span>Facebook</span></p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p style=
            "margin:5px 0 0 10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; font-style: italic;">
            "Company Slogan."</p>
        </div>

        <div><img alt="2015 Award" height="57" src=
        "Award Url" style=
        "margin:10px 0 0 0;" width="266"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var name     = $('#name').val();
        var position = $('#position').val();
        var phone    = $('#phone').val();
        var email    = $('#email').val();
        var lodge    = $('#lodge').val();
        var address  = $('#address').val();
        var facebook = $('#facebook').val();
        var website  = $('#website').val();
        var html     = $('#showInline');
        var file     = $('#html');

        $("#generate").click(function(){

          if(html.is(':checked'))
          {
             $('#inlineDIV').fadeIn("slow");


          }else
          {
            $('#inlineDIV').fadeOut("slow");
          }  

        });
   });
```

Comment: your Jquery is trying to access elements by ID, but I don't see any elements in your HTML with those IDs

Comment: at least you should not use inline styles

Comment: @Steve HTML is template and ID's he is accesing are in form from which OP generates signature.

Comment: @steve The elements given are from the form - the html below is what should be filled in from those elements :)

Comment: @falinsky Inline styles are used because it is template for email signature so they are needed. You don't attach css with signature.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change placeholders to something more specific like
`<p style="margin:0 0 5px 10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">[[[NAME]]]</p>`
 and then I would load template into single string, no need to do it line by line.

Then I would simply do `var updatedTemplate = bareTemplate.replace('[[[NAME]]]',name)`

You could also give ID's to your template like:
`<p id="name" style="margin:0 0 5px 10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;">Name</p>`
Then create element from template like:
`var templateElement = $(bareTemplate)`
and operate on it like:
`templateElement.find("#name").text(name)`

Where `bareTemplate` is this html posted in question.

If you load template to `file` then `bareTemplate` would be contents of file as string.

https://jsfiddle.net/gv2q6oos/1/

Comment: How would the html relate to the "bareTemplate"?

Comment: Updated answer, I think you load contents of template to ```file```

Comment: File or create another var that loads the template just for the purpose?